# Fastest hierarchical geo address, data lookup on least expensive hardware? NoSQL or SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, azure-storage, arangodb, nosql

I have 350,000 city addresses with Latitude and Longitude values, like this:

2500 HardToSpellName Street NW (quadrant), City, State, Country

It would seem that the best data structure would be a JSON file mostly in reverse order and have the user enter the query in that order:

Country.State.City.Quadrant.StreetType  - all these are repeated many times

Then switch to civic number data input as numbers are easy to spell;)  From the above, we would implement a lookup to populate a "Auto Complete" on the Street Name as it is prone to spelling errors.

The query of the data is always the same, one address input gets Lat/Long result.

Is this a good idea? How many records would be reasonable? How would you convert a table (csv) to JSON tree?

Is the main reason to use NoSQL the lower cost of hardware/hosting?

Comment: 350k records? That's **NOTHING** for a relational database, unless your DB server is an 8088-4.77mhz/640k machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best idea is to restrict the potential result set to as few records as possible, using the user's input.
This could be achieved by a combined index on [ Country, State, City, Quadrant, StreetType ] if users are expected to enter the search terms in this order.

The index will allow to filter on "Country" if that's the first and only input provided. If Country is chosen and "State" is entered, querying the index will restrict results to records for the entered combination of Country and State and so forth. In general, the more criteria you have, the further you can use it to narrow the results down. The requirement is that you use some sorted index and only query the indexed attributes from the left.

When the last criterion (StreetType) is entered, the result set is probably already quite small so you may return all street names from it to the application and create and auto-complete input box. 
You may alternative extend the index so it also covers street names. This will allow you to efficiently retrieve an alphabetic list of street names (and coordinates) for the search criteria.

As far as I understood, the data can be put into a flat table because all records have the same structure. Then a sorted index can be created on the to-be-indexed attributes. Any relational database should support that.

You may also use a NoSQL document database for this purpose, and it should also work fine.

To decide which is the best solution, I think you should also take your workload and other factors into account, e.g.
- will you have updates on the data and how frequently? do you need transactional isolation for reads and updates?
- what other operations should be running inside the database?
- can you live with a flat table structure or do you really need hierchical data, flexible schemas?